# React Native Firestore getting data problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to access the data from a Firestore collection called 'Targets' it returns:

`{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`

my firestore item is:
[item photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TREMz.png)

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MapView, { Circle } from 'react-native-maps';
import * as geolib from 'geolib';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
 
export default function MenuScreen() {
    const targetData = firestore().collection('Targets').where('isActive', '==', true).get()
    console.log(targetData)

}
```

I tried useState and other hooks but it still returns same data. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Is firestore initialize properly, are you able to get any data at all from the DB?

Comment: i just initialize firestore. it can reach methods @abalexandre

Comment: i reinstalled now and still same data

Answer (score 1):

`.get()` just returns a promise.. you need to continue on to get the data:

```
firestore().collection("Targets").where("isActive", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-8_3